# imagemap javascript toogle values in input fields when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do if its possible: I have an image with 2 clickable buttons(areas) in a webform(post), the users should click on or two buttons in the area and when they click submit button the server side should could read if the area is 0 or 1! If its possible to highlight/markup that click area of the image when its clicked(1) and toogle it if clicked again(0)

The only idea is doing it with imagemap and javascript, but other solutions are welcome!

I have an imagemap 2 two rect, I want it to change the value in a input field, first time it should be 1 and next click it should toogle to 0, Im not sure how to do that. Can someone help me?

Is i possible to highlight/markup that part of image when it should be great!

```
<form name="form">
<input type='text' name='test1' value='0' />
<input type='text' name='test2' value='0' />
<img src="plansets.gif" width="145" height="126" usemap="#foo">
<map name='foo'>
  <area shape='rect' coords="0,0,82,126" href='javascript:document.form.test1.value=1;' alt="test"/>
  <area shape='rect' coords="82,0,145,186" href='javascript:document.form.test2.value++;' alt="test2"/>
</map>

 </form>
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, what exactly you want.

Comment: Put the JS code within a `script` tag, and use proper event attaching method like `addEventListener`. Then in a function it's easy to convert the current value to a boolean, negate it with `!` and convert to a number again and set the result as a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/eor2tLrg/)

html

```
<form name="form">
<input type='text' name='test1' value='0' />
<input type='text' name='test2' value='0' />
<img src="plansets.gif" width="145" height="126" usemap="#foo">
<map name='foo'>
  <area shape='rect' coords="0,0,82,126" href='javascript:document.form.test1.value=1;' alt="test"/>
  <area shape='rect' id="test" coords="82,0,145,186" href='#' alt="test2"/>
</map>

 </form>
```

js

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    var $test2 =$("input[name='test2']");
    if($test2.val() == 1){
        $test2.val(0);
    }else{
        $test2.val(1);
    }
});
```

Is this what you expected to do?
use jquery could get the effect what you what.

Comment: Yes almost, I changed it to
       http://jsfiddle.net/eor2tLrg/1/

Comment: Is it possible to highlight/markup that click area of the image when its clicked(1) and toogle it if clicked again(0) in some way?